# get dynamically generated ajax textbox id

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I have created a web application in which I need to generate textboxes depending upon the number the user enters.I have used Ajax and created textboxes dynamically but these textboxes are not accessible from code-behind.I have used `find control` but to no use.This is the code I use to generate textbox.

```
if (txtnobranches.Text != "")
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(txtnobranches.Text) != 0)
                {
                    div_br.InnerHtml = "<table></table>";
                    tbl_br.Controls.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(txtnobranches.Text); i++)
                    {

                        TableRow rowbr = new TableRow();
                        TableCell cellname = new TableCell();
                        cellname.Text = "Branch Location " + i.ToString();
                        rowbr.Cells.Add(cellname);
                        TableCell cellvalue = new TableCell();
                        cellvalue.Text = "";
                        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                        txt.Text = "";
                        txt.ID = "txtbranchloc" + i.ToString();
                        cellvalue.Controls.Add(txt);
                        cellvalue.ID = "txtbranchloc" + i.ToString();
                        rowbr.Cells.Add(cellvalue);
                        tbl_br.Rows.Add(rowbr);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `txt.ID = "txtbranchloc" + i.ToString();`  this is the ID rite? Can you say what is your ultimate aim ?

Comment: this code genrate text-box with id as given above.Afetr genrateing i want to find texbox using this id but not able to find it returns null

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your table is generated the way you intended?  ie. all your table rows and cells and texboxes are displayed.  If they are I suggest going into your browser to "inspect element" and check to make sure your ID's are assigned properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the **element by name** using Request.Form["NameOfFormControl"] You will have to make little change in code.

**In javascript**

```
  txt.Name = "txtbranchloc" + i.ToString();
```

**In Code Behind**

**Note: Make sure you access it in postback otherwise you get null**

```
 if (Page.IsPostBack)
 {
    string firstTxtVal = Request.Form["txtbranchloc0"].ToString();
    string secondTxtVal = Request.Form["txtbranchloc1"].ToString();
 }
```

[Using Request.Form Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)